# found a bunch of DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot personal certificates installed on my system

Tags: google-chrome, security, internet-security, client-certificate

I was looking at my personal certificates in Google Chrome and found a bunch of DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot certs there. I don't know how these got there. Should I be concerned?

Comment: Have you ever installed the [Fiddler web debugging proxy](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?  It installs certs with that name in order to debug SSL traffic.  If not, you should be able to delete them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you should. In fact you should delete them. There's an adware that installs those certificates and injects encrypted HTML advertising content from various websites, hence SSL certificate.

**To find more of your certificates:**

Open *`mmc.exe`* --> <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> --> *`Certificates`* --> Click *`Add >`* --> *`My User account`* --> Click *`Finish`* --> Click *`OK`*

You also might want to run some or all of these:

- AdwCleaner
- Malwarebytes
- ComboFix
- CCleaner
- and finally an Anti-virus.

Update:

To make my answer more clear. If you have never installed Fiddler on your computer, chances are there's an Adware that installed the certificates.

From: https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore

> ### What is Telerik FiddlerCore?
>
> Progress® Telerik® FiddlerCore Embedded Engine is a .NET Class library
>   you can integrate into your .NET Framework applications. There is also
>   a .NET Standard 2.0 flavor of FiddlerCore that allows using it on any
>   platform implementing .NET Standard.
>
> Telerik FiddlerCore allows you to capture and modify HTTP and HTTPS
>   traffic just like Fiddler, without any of the Fiddler UI.
>
> ### Why Telerik FiddlerCore
>
> Battle-tested code used by millions of users of the Fiddler
>   application. Flexible licensing schemes for internal and public
>   distribution. Ongoing support from the core development team. Key
>   Features HTTP and HTTPS traffic capture and modification. Powerful
>   object model for content filtering and modification. Store and reload
>   web traffic. Support for virtually any client application. Support for
>   most devices via mobile proxy settings.

Fiddler installs these certificates so it can capture and inspect encrypted Web traffic (for debugging).

In which case you should also check your Internet Proxy settings.

Additional links:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/httpfiddler/V7TXBlJch6Y/SgXN_tYy0-EJ;context-place=forum/httpfiddler
- https://akhpark.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/whats-with-do_not_trust_fiddlerroot/

Comment: As @heavyd stated, the Fiddler web debugging proxy will install them to debug SSL traffic.

Comment: @heavyd Yes I know that but even Fiddler gives you a warning when installing them because malicious applications can use them since they get installed into your trusted store. Also, if you have never use Fiddler and found the certificates then the above applies.